# New Basement electrical wiring

Tags: electrical

I'm developing my basement, I'm done doing the framing and now the electrical, do I need a new set of circuit breakers for both lights and receptacles, and if so, what type?

Comment: How can we say, knowing literally nothing about your electrical system? Revise to add details, please.

Comment: Can you please post photos of your breaker panel?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate a) where you are (regulations are different in different locations.)  b) What  your current electrical setup is.

Answer (score 2):

The NEC does specify verbatim that certain "rooms" get dedicated / new circuits.

For example if you are adding a laundry in the basement, then that would require a 20 amp dedicated circuit for the receptacles only, not the lights!

If you are adding a kitchenette in the basement then that would require at least (2) 20 amp dedicated circuits for the receptacles on the counter top only and/or refrigerator/wall clock outlet, no other receptacles are allowed on that circuit!

Bathroom receptacles can catch other bathrooms as long as they are **not** tied into the bathroom lighting.  If the receptacles and lighting are sharing the same circuit, that bathroom circuit **cannot** feed other bathrooms.

The sq foot of the area is a factor for the "general lighting and receptacle loads".  The formula for that is P = sq.ft x 3  e.g., 1000 x 3 = 3000 watts.   General lighting and receptacles are non-continuous loads so you **do not** apply the 80%.

3000 watts divided into 120 volts = 25 amps, thus you would need at least (2) 15 amp circuits for a 1000 sq ft area for the general lighting/receptacles.

The formula is out-dated too as with new lower power consuming LEDs the 3watt(sq-ft) is not giving us a proper power measurement, but currently those are the rules.

Also, certain appliances may require a dedicated circuit.

In addition the to the above, AFCI/GFCI protection should be installed.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly *wiser* to have lights and receptacles on separate circuits.  That way, when you're going to town with the table saw, and you trip the breaker, you aren't in the pitch black with your fingers 3 inches from a spinning saw blade.   (saw blades do not have the courtesy of instantly stopping when the power fails.  They do make saws [which instantly stop if you touch them with your finger](https://www.sawstop.com), but I doubt that detection device will work if the power cuts out).